# Generator of Dynkin system is subset of another family

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

Let be $\mathcal{M}$ a family of sets that is $\cap$-stable and $\delta(\mathcal{M})$ denotes the Dynkin-system generated by $\mathcal{M}$.

We define
$$
\mathcal{G}_1:=\{A\in\delta(\mathcal{M})\mid A\cap B \in\delta(\mathcal{M})\text{ for all } B\in\mathcal{M}\}
$$
and see that $\mathcal{M}\in\mathcal{G}_1$ and that $\mathcal{G}_1$ is a Dynkin-system.

Next, we define
$$
\mathcal{G}_2:=\{A\in\delta(\mathcal{M})\mid A\cap B \in\delta(\mathcal{M})\text{ for all } B\in\delta(\mathcal{M})\}.
$$

---

Now, our professor stated that we can easily see that $\mathcal{M}\subseteq \mathcal{G}_2$. However, I don't see it. Moreover, I doubt that it's true but I couldn't produce a counter example. Maybe someone else can explain $\mathcal{M}\subseteq \mathcal{G}_2$ or show that this subset property is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $A\in \mathcal M$. $\{B \in \delta (\mathcal M): A\cap B \in \delta (\mathcal M) \}$ is a Dynkin-system which contains $\mathcal M$. Hence, it contains $\delta (\mathcal M)$. This means that every $B$ in $\delta (\mathcal M)$ belongs to $\{B \in \delta (\mathcal M): A\cap B \in \delta (\mathcal M) \}$. In other words, $B\in \delta (\mathcal M)$ implies $A\cap B \in \delta (\mathcal M)$, so $A \in \mathcal G_2$.  This proves that $\mathcal{M}\subseteq \mathcal{G}_2$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "this proves $\mathcal{M}\subseteq \mathcal{G}_2$"? I don't see it.

Comment: @Philipp I have added a few more lines.

Comment: Does the family $\mathcal{G}_1$ provided by our professor make any sense at all?

Comment: It does, but that is not relevant to $\mathcal{M}\subseteq \mathcal{G}_2$. @Philipp